# dom won't update until after clicking page - $scope.$apply

Tags: angularjs

I have an app where data is pushed into the angular framework from an outside service using:

```
$window.createAccount = function(success, data){
    CreateAccountService.setMessage(success,data);
}
```

In my service, I store a callback function and use it when CreateAccountService.setMessage is called.

The data is successfully passed through the service to the controller:

```
$scope.setMessage = function(success,json){
        console.log('setMessage:',success);
        $scope.errorMsg = 'create account successful?:'+success+'-'+json;
        $scope.$apply();
    }
```

My console.log traces accurately and $scope.errorMsg is set but the $scope.$apply() doesn't seem to be set until the user clicks anywhere on the page.

I'm a little boggled by this, because my approach works elsewhere.

Any thoughts?

Comment: My bet is you are expecting child scopes to update from a primitive...show all relevant code

Comment: so what do you mean child scopes? should I move it to rootScope?

Comment: No...might need to be an object but there isn't enough code shown to isolate what the problem is